# SQL find max mutual appearances

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns (film_id,actor_id), I need to find a pair of actors that made the largest number of mutual appearances in films,for example actor 10 and actor 20 have two movies together (1,3) , so i need to return 10,20

[image: the table looks simaller to this:]

Comment: Could you set up the structure and some data into http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: i uploaded a picture, hope its making things easier

Comment: its too big for fiddle to handle, but download sakila db from here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is what you exactly want or not, but try it:

```
select
    group_concat(actor_id) as actors
from (
    select actor_id, group_concat(movie_id order by movie_id) as movies
    from tbl1
    group by actor_id) t1
group by movies
having count(actor_id) = 2
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6650/5)

Comment: hmm. i tried runing it, I got zero rows returned, but the "having" tags is deffenlty a good aproche, i will google it a little bit :)

Comment: but i used your sqlfiddle link and its working, so maybe something wrong with my mySql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_concat()` probably along with `group by` like

```
select group_concat(actor_id) as multistarter
from movies
group by movie_id;
```

Comment: its returning false answer,  there isn't a max function in the query, and no count is present

Comment: I did,  I need to return 10,20